# Where do I insert this data into my code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to set a cache limit for my C# program. My program is creating files periodically and saving them to a folder. I want it so if the folder (C:\SysApp) hits this limit (150000KB) it will automatically start deleting the files starting with the oldest ones deleting only a certain amount at a time (149900KB).

So far I have this code:

```
private void DeleteOldFilesIfOverFolderLimit(string folderPath,
                                             long folderSizeLimit,
                                             long amountToDelete)
{
    var folder = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
    var files = folder.GetFiles();
    var folderSize = files.Sum(fi => fi.Length);

    if (folderSize > folderSizeLimit)
    {
        // Sort the list of files with the oldest first.
        Array.Sort(files,
                   (fi1, fi2) => fi1.CreationTime.CompareTo(fi2.CreationTime));

        var amountDeleted = 0L;

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            amountDeleted += file.Length;
            file.Delete();

            if (amountDeleted >= amountToDelete)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to figure out where I need to insert the specific data for my program (given in first paragraph in parenthesis).

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015.

Comment: What part of your code don't you understand? Look at the function parameters.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this question because its unclear exactly what you are asking. The answer can't be as simples as "pass it into the clearly named parameters in your function"... can it?

Comment: If it's configurable put it in app.config.  If it isn't then just have it as a `const` field in your class.

Comment: If you can write that function, I don't see how you can't know what `folderSizeLimit` means.

Comment: @SLaks I don't quite understand what parts to change. This is the best way I can think to explain it. (Sorry, I'm recovering from a brain tumor so it's hard for me to retrieve my words or explain things well.)
[link](http://tinypic.com/r/10f5mog/9)
Here's what I have so far of what I think might be right (I couldn't figure out how to add code on here so I made a link, sorry.)
Red, I think is where I put the full path of the folder (C:\SysApp).
Yellow, I think is where I put the folder size limit (150000KB).
Green, I think is where I put the amount to delete (149900KB).

Comment: You need to learn the basics of C# functions and parameters.

Comment: `DeleteOldFilesIfOverFolderLimit("C:\\Foo\\", 15*1024, 5*1024);`  That will delete 5KB of data from directory Foo if it is over 15KB... Everything in terms to file sizes are going to be the number of bytes. There's 1024 bytes in a kilobyte and 1024 kilobytes in a megabyte. So if you want to delete 5MB, it would be 5*1024*1024.

Comment: I am VERY new to this. I've been reading as much as I can online to try and learn how coding works, but I've been having an awful lot of trouble. I received this code from someone else on another forum that was trying to help me, but ultimately got too busy to help. I'm very sorry if I'm asking for too much. I just think it'd help me along with working out how everything works if I have real humans helping. This is my first program and it's the last bit I have to code that I've been working on for a little over a week with no answers.

Comment: @TyCobb So if I write the code like this it'd work?
`private void DeleteOldFilesIfOverFolderLimit(string C:\SysApp,
                                             long 150000,
                                             long 1499000)...'

Comment: Not in the slightest. Please go read a C# tutorial.

Comment: @TyCobb sorry, I meant If I write the code like this:
`private void DeleteOldFilesIfOverFolderLimit(string C:\SysApp,
                                             long 150*1024*1024,
                                             long 149*1024*1024)...'

Comment: Which one would you recommend? I've read a ton.

Comment: `DeleteOldFilesIfOverFolderLimit("C:\\SysApp", 150*1024*1024, 149*1024*1024);`

Comment: The question I have is **when** do you want to trigger this call? With `C#` you can create an executable and with Windows you can schedule to run it periodically, or you can make a program that while running it monitors a folder for deletion. It is up to you at this point to clarify this point.

Comment: @ja72 I want it to run constantly in the background and execute the call when it hits the cache limit of 150MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the project options and select settings:

[image: pic]

Enter the default values

[image: pic]

and your program can read these values (from the .settings file or the defaults) using the following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string folder=Properties.Settings.Default.folder;
    long limit=Properties.Settings.Default.sizeLimit;
    long delete=Properties.Settings.Default.toDelete;
}
```

If you change the settings value in the program you need to save the new values before exiting the application. This is done with `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`. This command creates a `.config` file with your values. These are read automatically when the program starts.

The contents are an `XML` file with the settings values clearly visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="SO_KeepStettings.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <SO_KeepStettings.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="folder" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\SysApp</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="sizeLimit" serializeAs="String">
                <value>157286400</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="toDelete" serializeAs="String">
                <value>156237824</value>
            </setting>
        </SO_KeepStettings.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you vert much!
Do you have any idea why it wouldn't let me edit the settings?
I figured out how to make them available before but I forgot, unfortunately.
Is it the mode I'm in or something?

Comment: Oh, I just closed VS and reopened it and it worked.

Just one question; do I have to paste the `static void Main(string[] args)` code into my project somewhere for this to work or will it automatically create it?

Comment: Oh sorry, also, what unit are the sizeLimit and toDelete values in? Bytes?

Comment: Is this right? http://tinypic.com/r/2hhjhaa/9
Sorry for all the questions and probably being way off and seriously misunderstanding what you mean.
I am REALLY grateful for your help, you have no idea. :D

Comment: the integer values are of `long` type (see picture #2). If you use `string` (like your link) then you have to convert the string into a number. Use `long.Parse()` function.

Comment: So I read this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) and learned some more about the `long` type which is very useful, but I still don't get how I should enter my units. I need the `sizeLimit` to be 150000KB and the 'toDelete` to be 149900KB. How would I write that into the value section of this "settings grid"?

Comment: Each application has a `.config` file, and the values are stored there. If there is no `.config` file because the `Save()` method has never been called then the values are the defaults that are stored internally in your program (in the settings under properties).

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I mean. I just want to know what format to type the data (ie 150000KB) in. Earlier in my program I used a 32 bit signed integer and I typed in 10000 for 10 seconds because the format is in millesconds. I want to know what numbers to type into [this area](http://tinypic.com/r/qsusz6/9) to match 150000KB and [this area](http://tinypic.com/r/2urv5e0/9) to match 149900KB. Does that make sense?

Comment: I used `long` because you posted code that uses `long`. The values I typed equate to `150*1024*1024=157286400` and `149*1024*1024=156237824` respectively. I used a calculator! See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx for how to type different types of integers as `literals` (directly) in your code . For example `long x = 100L`.

Comment: Oooh
So I entered the values like you showed in picture 2. All the errors were fixed and I was able to build the program successfully, but when I ran it it never deleted any of the pictures.
(Also, I don't have enough reputation to chat and stack overflow is telling me to avoid extended discussion in the comments. Can we maybe email or something? It's okay, if not.) Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the amounts got lost in confusion. I only said `150*1024*1024` and `149*1024*1024` because TyCobb said that's how I'd write `150000KB` and `149900KB`

Comment: You can ignore [SO] complaining. Your issue now is beyond the scope of this question. You need to award the most helpful answer and ask a new question specific to deleting the files. Remember to use a [small verifiable code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the compiles to illustrate your problem.

Comment: I can't ask a new question for another week and I don't have a week to wait, though. Plus I'm just trying to figure out this last little bit of your answer.

Comment: I just need to know: Is it 157286400/156237824 bytes or kilobytes or megabytes, etc.? I'm suspecting bytes, but I need you so I can know the answer because only you know.

Comment: Oh, I figured out why it didn't work. I didn't add `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` Where do I add this?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting files is sketchy, if you accidentally pass in a malformed string or simply the wrong string then you will be losing data, such as accidentally deleting your only copy of your PhD thesis or destroying your operating system. So, I'm just going to show you how to call a method instead of showing you how to use this code you were given:

Starting with a [Hello World!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288463(v=vs.71).aspx) example:

```
public class Hello1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        // This is here only to pause the console window so it stays open.
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now let's implement our own method to print *any* string to the console:

```
public class Hello1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        PrintToConsole("Hello World!");

        // This is here only to pause the console window so it stays open.
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintToConsole(string stringToPrintToConsole)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(stringToPrintToConsole);
    }
}
```

Lastly, let's pass in another parameter to control how many times the line is printed:

```
public class Hello1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        PrintToConsole("Hello World!", 5);

        // This is here only to pause the console window so it stays open.
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintToConsole(string stringToPrintToConsole, long numberOfTimesToPrint)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTimesToPrint; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(stringToPrintToConsole);
        }
    }
}
```

You were given a method but no where are you *calling* that method. Note how in my program I have to call `PrintToConsole()` somewhere, and this being a console application the entire program starts and finishes in `Main()` so that is where I put the code. You could technically take the body of your method and paste it directly into Main, then everywhere you see the usage of the variable `folderPath` you replace it with the actual string `"C:\\SysApp"` and likewise with the other 2 parameters and the program would work the same.

Comment: That helps me understand a ton of other things I never understood before. Thank you. :)

I thought this code needed to be posted in a class, though. So how could it be pasted into Main?

I tried replacing every instance of `folderPath` with `C:\\SysApp` and every instance of `folderSizeLimit` with `150*1024*1024` and every instance of `amountToDelete` with `149*1024*1024`
I ended up with 78 errors. I must've really misunderstood what you meant.

[Here are the errors in a Google Sheet.] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D5gbA22v7N3fLdHdo25H1fd7M6acr34hB4St09iS094/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: There's a website that will compile and run c# code called dotnetfiddle. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q0EfG8) is what I was getting at. Note that I had to add `using System.IO;`, `using System.Linq;` at the top because `DirectoryInfo()` is really `System.IO.DirectoryInfo()` and `Sum()` is really in the `System.Linq` namespace. Note also that when you "run" the program it gives an access exception because the owner of the website smartly disallows anyone access to the `C:\ ` drive, so our code is not able to delete the `C:\SysApp` folder even if it existed on that system.

Comment: And for clarity now that I see your screenshots, when I say "body of the method", I mean everything between the opening and closing brackets and NOT including its signature, where this line is basically the method's "signature": `private void DeleteOldFilesIfOverFolderLimit(string folderPath,                                            long folderSizeLimit,                                             long amountToDelete)` -- I.e., copying the body of a method means ignoring that line and copying everything between the brackets.

Comment: So wouldn't the code now work if I added the FileIOPermission?
I tried this on my program in Visual Studio, but it came back with these 7 errors. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D5gbA22v7N3fLdHdo25H1fd7M6acr34hB4St09iS094/edit?usp=sharing          I know I can just hover over the errors and learn about them, but I still don't quite understand how to fix them.

Comment: @Theresa.Eckert I can't tell you what's causing those errors without seeing all of your code. You must have an extra bracket somewhere. The code I linked [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q0EfG8) will work on your machine if you copy and paste the ENTIRE thing into your file, completely erase all code in your file and paste that entire thing in and it will work. Creating a program that deletes files as one of your very first projects is dangerous, you can easily mess up and end up erasing things off of the computer or literally breaking it to where it doesn't even boot any more.

Comment: @Theresa.Eckert Yes that should work fine. You left your gmail password in that program you just linked me. I flagged your comment so a moderator can maybe remove it but you should change your gmail password asap and also delete your comment if a moderator doesn't beat you to it.